# Как сделать скриншот нужного размера?

Tags: linux, node.js, phantomjs, screenshots

Хочу сделать с помощью PhantomJS сриншот сайта. Нашел в примерах идущих с ним скрипт rasterize.js но не как не пойму с какими параметрами его запускать чтобы получить необходимый мне размер скриншота.

Нужно сделать jpg картинку размером 400х300пк, со скриншотам сайта, и только один экран, т.е. если страница длинная и проматывается вниз то не надо делать скрин всей страницы, а только то что помещается на один экран 1900*600пк

Comment: Это нужно сделать именно на js? Могу предложить вариант на питоне.

Comment: Да нужно на JS фантоме. Раньше пользовался сервисом s-shot.ru делал запросы к нему, получал скрин, но что то в последнее время он как то не стабильно стал работать. Решил на фантоме сделать, то же самое чтобы не зависеть от сторонних сервисов.

Answer (score 0):

```
    {
  "id": "sanity_tests",
  "viewports": [
    {
      "label": "phone",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 3294
    },
    {
      "label": "tablet",
      "width": 768,
      "height": 3294
    },
    {
      "label": "desktop",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 3294
    }
  ],
  "scenarios": [
    {
      "label": "home_page",
      "url": "https://some-page.com/",
      "hideSelectors": [],
      "removeSelectors": [],
      "hoverSelector": "",
      "selectors": [
        "body"
      ],
      "delay": 4000,
      "misMatchThreshold": 0.1
    },
    {
      "label": "contacts",
      "url": "https://some-page.com/contacts",
      "hideSelectors": [],
      "removeSelectors": [],
      "hoverSelector": "",
      "selectors": [
        "body"
      ],
      "delay": 4000,
      "misMatchThreshold": 0.1
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "bitmaps_reference": "backstopjs_tests/dev_reference",
    "bitmaps_test": "backstopjs_tests/dev_test",
    "html_report": "backstopjs_tests/dev_html_report",
    "ci_report": "backstopjs_tests/dev_ci_report"
  },
  "casperFlags": [
    "--ignore-ssl-errors=true",
    "--ssl-protocol=any"
  ],
  "report": ["CLI", "browser"],
  "engine": "phantomjs",
  "cliExitOnFail": false,
  "debug": false
}
```

И в размерах к устройству указываете нужные вам размеры

Comment: Пожалуйста, дайте пояснение к ответу. Кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/780938/edit) перенесите комментарий в ответ.

Comment: Эм.. Не вижу причин, по которым этот конфиг хоть как-то отвечает на заданный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сделать скриншот сайта с помощью PhantomJS и получить картинку размером 400x300 пикселей, а также ограничить скриншот одним экраном 1900x600 пикселей, вы можете использовать скрипт rasterize.js следующим образом:

Убедитесь, что у вас установлен PhantomJS.
Сохраните следующий HTML-код в файл с именем `rasterize.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>PhantomJS Screenshot</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    // Замените URL ниже на адрес сайта, который вы хотите снимать.
    var url = 'http://example.com';
    var width = 1900;
    var height = 600;
    var clipWidth = 400;
    var clipHeight = 300;

    var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.viewportSize = { width: width, height: height };
    page.open(url, function (status) {
      if (status === 'success') {
        // Устанавливаем размер окна просмотра для обрезки скриншота.
        page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: clipWidth, height: clipHeight };
        // Делаем задержку для полной загрузки страницы (если это необходимо).
        setTimeout(function () {
          page.render('screenshot.jpg', { format: 'jpg', quality: '100' });
          phantom.exit();
        }, 2000); // Задержка в миллисекундах перед созданием скриншота.
      } else {
        console.log('Не удалось открыть страницу: ' + url);
        phantom.exit(1);
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Теперь, запустите PhantomJS и скрипт rasterize.js с помощью следующей команды:

```
    phantomjs rasterize.js rasterize.html
```

После выполнения этой команды, скрипт откроет указанный URL (замените 'http://example.com' на нужный вам) в браузере PhantomJS, подождет 2 секунды для полной загрузки страницы (вы можете изменить это значение), обрежет скриншот до размеров 400x300 пикселей и сохранит его как 'screenshot.jpg' в текущей директории.

Обратите внимание, что PhantomJS устарел и больше не поддерживается. Рекомендуется использовать современные инструменты, такие как Puppeteer (для Node.js) или Playwright, которые предоставляют функциональность PhantomJS и более новые возможности.

Comment: [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)